# 404 page if url contains /index.php/

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a htaccess file that redirects all traffic to my index.php for routing.

The app works with a url like this as well "example.com/index.php/blog/"

I and trying to 404 the url if it looks like "example.com/index.php/blog/" but let the url "example.com/blog/" go through

Htaccess file

```
# Send the URI to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a new rule to send 404 for your new requirement:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

# Send the URI to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```